# detect and redirect to another domains whit javascript

Tags: javascript

any way to redirect ("http://domain1.com","https://mydomain1.com")  to "http://mynewsite.com" whit javascript? I no have idea.

**structure is like this:**

**list domains:** domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com

**if location is** domain1.com **or** domain2.com **or** domain3.com **(http and https <-- Important)**

**make redirection** to mynewsite.com (<- only http)

Thanks guys.

Comment: You should probably either use a script language or just HTML headers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use JS, but PHP. Can you use PHP? See below (tweak it a bit). Good luck!

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on") {    
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
window.location.hostname
```

and

```
window.location.protocol
```

to identify your current location and then use

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//newSite.com"
```

to redirect

Comment: Why its important if the current domains is http or https if you want to redirect all to http? then you should simply redirect to "http://mynewwebsite.com" or did I miss something?

Comment: Is not important, but i need to detect the  http o https protocol too, both cases redirects to mynewsite.com, the code will be inside a js